# SilverStripe 3 multiple UploadField issue

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm having an issue with multiple UploadFields in the SilverStripe CMS.

When uploading a bunch of images, they appear to upload and preview correctly. However on saving the page and reloading and viewing the front end, there is no image. Where the preview should be is just a blank image and there is no URL output on the front end.

The image is being uploaded to the assets directory and the path to the file in the database is correct. I'm at a bit of a loss now.

Here's the code from my Page model

```
<?php
class Page extends SiteTree {

public static $db = array(
);  

public static $many_many = array(
    'Images' => 'Image'
);  

    public function getCMSFields() {
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

    $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Main', new UploadField('Images','Images',$this->Images()), 'Content');

    return $fields;
}   

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it just the front end of the site your having issues with? Could you show the code you're using in the template file for showing the images?

it should look like

```
<% loop $Images %>
    $setSize(150,150) // whatever you want to use here
<% end_loop %>
```

You can't use $Image.whatever, it won't work.

Comment: It's not just front end, it's in the CMS too.

Comment: trying removing the $this->Images() from addFieldsToTab() function.

Comment: Had the same issue, removing $this->Images() resolved it. Not sure where I copy/pasted that from...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using default theme "simple", have created a page of type "Page" at backend (CMS) , uploaded images and have published page.

Go to :

> Root folder 
>              -> themes 
>                       -> simple
>                                 -> templates
>                                               -> Layout
>                                                         -> open file "Page.ss"

Type (solution provided by "Ryan M" above)

```
<% loop $Images %>
    $setSize(150,150)
<% end_loop %>
```

After

```
<div class="content">$Content</div>
```

Go to frontend by giving your page URL in browser's address bar.